# Rolling cumulative product

Tags: r, cumulative-sum

I have data that looks like this

```
    A    B    
 1  1    1
 2  3    
 3  5    
 4  7
```

where I want to calculate the following rolling cumulative product in column B. In Excel I  would have the following formula

```
B2 = (1 + A2/10)*B1
```

I so far have tried using a helper column that is the results of 1 + Ax/100 , and one exactly the same just lagged by 1 which then gets multiplied by each other. Which wont work as the rolling product isn't applied. I also tried s.th like

```
rollapply(columnm,1,FUN = prod, fill = NA, align = 'left')
```

unfortunately it still doesn't work.

I would expect to get these results for B

```
    A    B    
 1  1    1
 2  3    1.3
 3  5    1.95
 4  7    3.315
```

[EDIT]

As an extension to the original question, is there a way of doing the same rolling product in an ifelse statement based on an additional column?

```
    A    B   C 
 1  1    1   1
 2  3    1   1
 3  5    0
 4  7    0
```

The excel equivalent would be

```
C3 = IF(B3=0,(1+A3/10)*C2,1)
```

I couldn't get the accepted solution working for this case as it is always referring to just the data in column A and I end up with the same results as in the previous solution.

I would expect the following results

```
    A    B   C 
 1  1    1   1
 2  3    1   1
 3  5    0   1.5
 4  7    0   2.55
```

thanks in advance

Comment: Why don't you use a for loop?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is this what you want?

```
A=c(1,3,5,7) 
cumprod(c(1,(A[-1]/10+1)))

> cbind(A,B=cumprod(c(1,(A[-1]/10+1))))
     A     B
[1,] 1 1.000
[2,] 3 1.300
[3,] 5 1.950
[4,] 7 3.315
```